# GWT RequestFactory: IllegalArgumentException for setter only fields

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Why is it mandatory to have both getters and setters for a field in RF Proxy interfaces? For some fields (like plain text password), you want setters only.
e.g.

```
@ProxyFor(value = User.class)
public interface UserProxy extends ValueProxy {
    void setPassword(String password);
}
```

User class has both getters and setters.

```
public class User implements Serializable {

private String password;

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

When I set the password on proxy, I get an IllegalArgumentException:

```
UserProxy user = userRequest.create(UserProxy.class);
user.setPassword("abc")
```

Above code results in following error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: password
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AutoBeanCodexImpl.doCoderFor(AutoBeanCodexImpl.java:525)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.setProperty(AbstractAutoBean.java:276)
...
...

This error goes away if I add a 'getPassword()' method in UserProxy interface but that defeats the purpose. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can have a `getter` without a `setter` but not the other way round.

See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/google-web-toolkit/RequestFactory%2420issue%243A%2420proxy%2420must%2420include%2420getter%2420if/google-web-toolkit/uaxQvAH-Z_k/ZAZMkoE70GwJ) and this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5760).